# i want cast a string component to render item for react native

Tags: string, components, render, react-native

I want to cast this string

```
const test = '<View style={styles.loginbox}>
                    <Text style={styles.textInput}></Text>
                    <Text style={styles.email}> </Text></View>'

render() { return ({test})}
```

to a component and use it as below

```
render() {return { {test})}
```

because I want to read this string as JSON from the server.